# Можно ли сделать автоматическое создание новых страниц сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны, ссылки, автоматизация

У меня есть простенький сайт на WordPress. На его главной странице - меню, сайдбар и список последних новостей. Каждая новость - блок с кратким описанием и ссылкой на полный текст.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы используя заданный шаблон html/css, для каждой новой новости формировалась новая страница сайта, где выводился бы ее полный текст, и генерировалась ссылка (используя id, data или не важно что), которая бы и использовалась в соответствующем блоке на главной странице?

Comment: Не совсем понятно про связь полной статьи с главной. Чего именно хотите добиться?

Comment: @EduardMisk  связь - как в обычном новостном сайте. На главной располагаются краткие содержания новостей, со ссылками на саму новость. И при переходе по ссылке открывается соответствующая статься с полным текстом.  
Я хочу узнать, как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой записи в WP формировалась новая страница у сайта с этим текстом. А на главной странице было краткое содержание со ссылкой

Comment: По факту, страница с полным содержанием статьи системой создается после перехода в состояние "опубликовано" (хотя предосмотр доступен администратору), а её шаблон по стандарту содержится в single.php в папке с темой. Там код может быть какой угодно.

Comment: ВП так и работает Непонятно в чём вопрос.